# ActivityIndicator in asynchronous - Swift

Tags: swift, asynchronous, activity-indicator, loadimage

I have heavy code - loading images asynchronously.
[I am using Grand Central Dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269716/activity-indicator-not-appearing/31270819#31270819),
but Activity Indicator does not working. Help me find the error, please

```
func loadImage() {
    if let imageUrl = NSURL(string: "http://\($url)/1.jpg") {
        let imageRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imageUrl)
        let queue: NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(imageRequest, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if data != nil {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data)!
                self.productImageView.image = self.image

            }
        })
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.imageActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in

    self.loadImage()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.imageActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    })
    });


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's happening because you are using the `imageActivityIndicator` in `viewDidLoad` and the views haven't been added to the main view yet, so if your code would work if you moved it to `viewWillAppear` function.

Plus you have to hide it when the image finished loading, so this makes your code like this:

```
func loadImage() {
    if let imageUrl = NSURL(string: "http://skidon.info/1.jpg") {
        let imageRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imageUrl)
        let queue: NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(imageRequest, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if data != nil {

                self.image = UIImage(data: data)!
                self.productImageView.image = self.image

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.imageActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    self.imageActivityIndicator.hidden = true
                })

            }
        })
    }
}


override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()

    self.imageActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in

        self.loadImage()

    });


}
```

Comment: Thanks! So, now I am using  the 'imageActivityIndicator' in 'viewDidLoad' again and fix 'dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()'. And use **Hides When Stopped** in storyboard. Now it's work! Thanks!